# I want to copy bytes from file to string

Tags: assembly

The code below shows a piece of my program which can copy bytes (one byte at a time) from one file to another. What should i do to make it copy bytes from file and save it into the string?

```
reading:

;READ ONE BYTE.

    mov ah, 3FH             ;read from the file
    mov bx, handle          ;normal file
    mov cx, 1               ;HOW MANY BYTES TO READ.
    mov dx, offset buffer   ;THE BYTE WILL BE STORED HERE.
    int 21h                 ;NUMBER OF BYTES READ RETURNS IN AX.

;CHECK EOF (END OF FILE).

cmp ax,0                ;IF AX == 0 THEN EOF.
je  eofp

;WRITE BYTE TO THE SECOND FILE.           

    mov ah, 40h                            ; write to 
    mov bx, handle2                        ; file handle   
    mov dx, offset buffer                 ; where to find data to write    
    mov cx, 1                              ;LENGTH OF STRING IN CX.    
    int 21h    
    jmp reading                            ;REPEAT PROCESS.

eofp:
```

Comment: _"and save it into the string"_ What string?

Comment: In line `mov dx,offset buffer` you save it to the string. It will remain there. You just have to set right count of bytes to read from file for reading whole file. Of course, if you use 16-bit version of assembly you have just `64KB` in data segment - that is 65536B. So if you have file longer than 64KB you can't even store its content in string variable. Maybe you can use other segments because you also have approx 65536 segments available, but it will be much more tricky. And that also stands for other architectures (32-bit) just different numbers - sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a pointer to the string, use the pointer to store the byte where the pointer points to, then move the pointer forward, here is the code :

```
    lea  si, mystring       ;SI POINTS TO A STRING.  <======================

reading:

;READ ONE BYTE.
    mov ah, 3FH             ;read from the file
    mov bx, handle          ;normal file
    mov cx, 1               ;HOW MANY BYTES TO READ.
    mov dx, offset buffer   ;THE BYTE WILL BE STORED HERE.
    int 21h                 ;NUMBER OF BYTES READ RETURNS IN AX.

;CHECK EOF (END OF FILE).
    cmp ax,0                ;IF AX == 0 THEN EOF.
    je  eofp

;SAVE BYTE IN STRING.                               <======================
    mov  al, buffer         ;AL = BYTE READ.
    mov  [ si ], al         ;SAVE BYTE IN CURRENT POSITION.
    inc  si                 ;MOVE POINTER TO NEXT POSITION.

    jmp reading             ;REPEAT PROCESS.

eofp:
```

Notice how, at the beginning, SI points the the string. After checking EOF we store the read byte in [ SI ], then increment SI (here we appreciate the difference between SI and [ SI ] ).

But a second string is not necessary. We already have DX pointing to "buffer", move it before the label "reading", and, after reading, let's increase it (it's necessary to intialize DX before "reading" or it will save all the read bytes in the same position):

```
    mov dx, offset buffer   ;THE BYTE WILL BE STORED HERE.  <==========================
reading:

;READ ONE BYTE.
    mov ah, 3FH             ;read from the file
    mov bx, handle          ;normal file
    mov cx, 1               ;HOW MANY BYTES TO READ.
    int 21h                 ;NUMBER OF BYTES READ RETURNS IN AX.

    inc dx                  ;POSITION FOR NEXT BYTE. <================================

;CHECK EOF (END OF FILE).
    cmp ax,0                ;IF AX == 0 THEN EOF.
    je  eofp

    jmp reading             ;REPEAT PROCESS.

eofp:
```

To make the process more efficient you can read bytes not one at a time but two at a time, or ten by ten.

As Gondil said, this will work for small files, less than 64Kb. For bigger files you would need to allocate memory (but that's for another question).

Comment: it helped alot but i still occured one problem in my codes which i posted it right now but in that problem i know that i am missing something not too much. But this actually was the key part of my project. Thanks

Comment: actually i figured it out. Thank you so much. You helped me alot